# how to do a facebook like to a given post-id on my android app

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate my android app with facebook API.

I'm getting from my server a `postId` and I want the user to be able to

"like" that post on facebook from my android app.

I have search the facebook developers docs

but found nothing regarding such like, only login, share (android)

or like (from html page).

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: can you poste the final code (working) ? Im having the same doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a POST request to: `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes`.

Don't forget to include your token.

For this you need to have extended permissions set up properly, to allow liking of posts.

Comment: can you poste the final code (working) ? Im having the same doubt.

Comment: how exactly to include the auth token?